# How do I automate adding data to a table in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm looking at a website which does a similar thing:

```html
                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                  <td class="text--gray text--gray">TOTAL</td>
                  <td class="text--green text--green sorting_1" style="">2,548,592</td>
                  <td class="text--green text--green" style="">↑ 75,489 (3.05%)</td>

                  <td class="text--orange text--orange" style="">41,029</td>
                  <td class="text--red text--red" style="">175,905</td>
                  <td class="text--red text--red" style="">↑ 5,929 (3.49%)</td>

                  <td class="text--blue text--blue" style="">696,776</td>
                  <td class="text--yellow text--yellow" style="">1,675,000</td>
                </tr>
```

The data in this table updates every day. There are around 200 of these rows.

How is the site doing this? I'm really confused.

I am getting my data from pdfs online, but have no idea how to automate it into a table of around 200 row (and also rearrange the rows so the order makes more sense).

Comment: More information needed: how are you getting the data? How is it structured? Your question is extremely broad without any specific problem statement.

Comment: @Terry please check again! thank you.

Comment: What do you mean automate? Do you mean build the table from scratch with the data that you are receiving? If so then you would use a loop. You could then use the javascript `.sort()` function to sort them some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Terry said, I think we would need more information. 
What do you mean by

> How is the site doing this? I'm really confused.

What is 'this'. What do you need to do exactly?

If you have the data and you want to create more rows in that table, with the same format, you could use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and do something like this:

```
function createRow(data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7){
    var template = `
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="text--gray text--gray">${data0}</td>
      <td class="text--green text--green sorting_1" style="">${data1}</td>
      <td class="text--green text--green" style="">${data2}</td>

      <td class="text--orange text--orange" style="">${data3}</td>
      <td class="text--red text--red" style="">${data4}</td>
      <td class="text--red text--red" style="">${data5}</td>

      <td class="text--blue text--blue" style="">${data6}</td>
      <td class="text--yellow text--yellow" style="">${data7}</td>
    </tr>
    `;
    return template
}

var data0 = 'TOTAL'
var data1 = '2,548,592';
var data2 = '↑ 75,489 (3.05%)';
var data3 = '41,029';
var data4 = '175,905';
var data5 = '↑ 5,929 (3.49%)';
var data6 = '696,776';
var data7 = '1,675,000';
// get your data from wherever you need to.
var row1 = createRow(data0,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7);
var row2 = createRow('TEST','111','222','333','444','555','666','777');
// do whatever you need with your rows.
console.log(row1);
console.log(row2);
```

However, I am not sure this is what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this - I need to have like 200 rows of each template, however, with 4 pieces of data for each.

Comment: Hi, I think you will need to provide a more complete example and explain exactly what you need.
What do you mean by '4 pieces of data'.?
What do you mean by 'I need to have 200 rows'? And of what templates?

Comment: essentially - I have 200 countries, each with 4 sets of data: data1, data2, data3, data 4. I need to present this in a table. Each row consists of: Countryname, data1, data2, data3, data4.

Comment: Hi! OK, but what is the problem then? with the example I provided, you can now do this. Don't you? just loop through your rows and create a row with the data.      `for each conutryData -> row = createRow(data1, data2,data3,data4); append row to your table.`